Passing Sample Weights to Sklearn Pipeline object with XGBoost
There are some good questions on this topic, however, I haven't found any solution to this error involving using XGBoost models with sample_weight in sklearn's Pipeline framework.
Here is my example and the subsequent error:
from xgboost_distribution import XGBDistribution
from scipy.stats import nbinom
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# ... split dataset into X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, and sample_wgt

model = XGBDistribution(
    distribution="negative-binomial"
)

pipe = Pipeline(
  [
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('model', model)
  ]
)

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train, model__sample_weight=sample_wgt)

But I get the following warning message:
WARNING: /workspace/src/learner.cc:742: 
Parameters: { "sample_weight" } are not used.

I know the Pipeline object is clunky with accepting parameters, but how can I ensure the XGB model accepts the sample weights?

I think you should set pipe.set_fit_request(sample_weight=True), its default is sklearn.utils.metadata_routing.UNCHANGED

@Ze'evBen-Tsvi unfortunately, this gives the following error: AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'set_fit_request'

I'm sorry, you are right that's the model attribute https://xgboost-distribution.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/xgboost_distribution.XGBDistribution.html#xgboost_distribution.XGBDistribution.set_fit_request
